# PHP htaccess multiple variables

Tags: php, .htaccess

Hi I'm using the following htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /JustSnacksNew/


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products\.php\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9,a-z-]+)$ Products.php?category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewProduct\.php\?category=([^\s&]+)&product=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewProduct\?category=([^\s&]+)&product=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9,a-z-]+)$ ViewProduct.php?category=([^\s&]+)&product=$1 [L,NC,QSA]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]
```

In the first rule i'm passing one variable.It's working fine.But in the second rule i'm passing two variables.But it is redirecting to the first rule.
Please help me to fix this.

First url i'm passing is : `./Products.php?category=catname`

Second url passing is : `./ViewProduct.php?category=catname&product=product`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /JustSnacksNew/

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /ViewProduct(?:\.php)?\?category=([^&]+)&product=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [R=302,L]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /Products(?:\.php)?\?category=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1? [R=302,L]

# skip all files and directories from rewrite rules below
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

# PHP hiding rule
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [L]

RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9-]+)/?$ Products.php?category=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
RewriteRule ^([A-Z,0-9-]+)/([A-Z,0-9-]+)/?$ ViewProduct.php?category=$1&product=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Comment: thanks bro.It's working fine.Now i'm working on sub domain.When i move the project to domain what are all the changes i need to do in htaccess file.Please..

Comment: Nothing change for domain. Or eventually `RewriteBase`.